# How do you defeat the giant dragon in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

**Dragons Lair** is the last map in the single player campaign in clash of clans. If you check the clan castle, there is a big golden colored dragon appears and it will kill my heroes and troops in one shot. How do I defeat that dragon as a town hall 10 player?

Comment: We need more information to answer this question in an in-scope way. What *exact* troop composition does your army have? Where on the screen are you dropping your troops? Can you provide a screenshot of the map at the point where you've just dropped your troops in?

Comment: @TylerH I have troops unlocked up to the miner in the barracks, bowler in the dark barracks, up to clone and bat spells. I use a typical Town hall 10 army-the pekka bobat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly work for a team good for you, or check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_g_WwN_DmYk) video(Valkyrie baloon), [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqPpgACi8Ew)(baby drag valk wizard) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8iqHYviRdc)(balloon dragon). They all have different troops to use, but the main plan is to eagle artillery, tank and use your win conditions

Comment: Answers are expected to stand on their own. As such, links to off-site content should be accompanied with the useful content behind that link. Otherwise, when those links die, this answer loses what value it had.